# Get product stock back alert customers details programmatically

Tags: magento, sms, magento-1.9, product, stock

I have to get product stock back alert customers details(Telephone, Products for stock back alert, etc) programmatically.

I know that **Mage_ProductAlert_Model_Observer::process()** will send email alerts to customers, Sameway I need to send SMS(with SMS API) to all customers when products are back in stock.

I have found that below code in **app/code/core/Mage/ProductAlert/Model/Observer.php**

```
public function process() {
        $email = Mage::getModel('productalert/email');
        /* @var $email Mage_ProductAlert_Model_Email */
        $this->_processPrice($email);
        $this->_processStock($email);
        $this->_sendErrorEmail();

        return $this;
    }
```

Here I tried to rewrite that class & connect my SMS API to send SMS to customers to notify for product back in stock but its not working.

Can anyone share how to get that customers details(phone, products)? and how to configure SMS API to send sms?

Comment: check table for this model Mage::getModel('productalert/email'); it contain customer id or email then load customer details by id and get all related data from customer table